# How to get reference of DropDownList into codebehind?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview, updatepanel

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  Onrowupdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" onrowediting="GridView1_RowEditing">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Test">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="up1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                            OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                            <asp:ListItem>Test1</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Test2</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Test3</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SS") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rate">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="up2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" />
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

How to get reference of `DropDownList2` in `DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged` when grid is in edit mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After editing your question. you can achieve like...

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList DropDownList2 = ((DropDownList)((DropDownList)sender).Parent.FindControl("DropDownList2"));
}
```

Comment: It doesn't exist outside of edit mode - it is part of your edit template.

Comment: @james; then you are looking in RowUpdating event ? I have update my answer.

Comment: @jams; Updated my answer. try now.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access it in `GridView1_RowEditing`. You'll need to assign it to a control using something like:

```
DropDownList list = e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList1") as DropDownList;
```

**EDIT:** Based on the new info, this should do it:

```
int index = -1;

protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
 index = e.Row.Index;
}

protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 DropDownList DropDownList2 = GridView1.Rows[index].FindControl("DropDownList2") as DropDownList;
}
```

Comment: Grid is in edit mode DropDownList1 is visible, at that time I have to get reference of it outside grid.

Comment: It doesn't exist outside of edit mode - it is part of your edit template. Do you mean you need to get the value from it after it has changed? I see the autopostback on there.

Comment: @ jesus.tesh: `NULL`reference  is return.

Comment: Maybe the autopostback on your DropDownList causes the GridView to no longer be in edit mode? I know you have the UpdatePanels in there, but I cannot understand why it would give a null reference? DropDownList2 is in the same row as DropDownList1, so the only thing I can think is that you are no longer in edit mode for the GridView?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get a reference to the dropdown in the codebehind since it doesn't exist. The dropdown will only exist in update mode in your example so you're out of luck there. However, you might be able to add one dynamically, that is, creating `GridView` or adding the templates in the codebehind.

If you provide some more information about what your actual problem is we might find an alternative solution.